# Build .ipa failed in Codemagic iOS native

Tags: ios, xcode, codemagic

I am trying to build .ipa file in codemagic, but it fails with below message

> Archive
> Execute "xcodebuild -project . -scheme Optivio -archivePath build/ios/xcarchive/_ijalmu93.xcarchive archive COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO"
>
> Failed to archive .
>
> Build failed :| Step 7 script `Build .ipa` exited with status code 66

and my code in yaml file for build ipa is,

> xcode-project build-ipa --project "$XCODE_PROJECT" --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"

I don't have workspace, only project. when archive in Xcode got success.

Code magic screenshot: https://ibb.co/YjFg0gh

My full yaml file below,

```
workflows:
ios-testApp:
  name: ios_testApp
  environment:
    vars:
      XCODE_PROJECT:: “TestApp.xcodeproj" # <-- Put the name of your workspace here.
      XCODE_SCHEME: "TestApp" # <-- Put the name of your scheme here.
      # Set up env vars for manual codesigning (See - https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing-yaml/signing-ios/)
      CM_CERTIFICATE: Encrypted(…….) # <-- Put your encrypted distribution certificate here.
      CM_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD: Encrypted(…….) # <-- Put your encrypted distribution certificate password here.
      CM_PROVISIONING_PROFILE: Encrypted(…….) # <-- Put your encrypted provisioning profile here.
    xcode: 12.4
    cocoapods: default
  triggering:
    events:
      - push
      - tag
      - pull_request
    branch_patterns:
      - pattern: 'master'
        include: true
        source: true
  scripts:
    - name: Initialize keychain to be used for codesigning using Codemagic CLI 'keychain' command
      script: |
        keychain initialize
    - name: set up provisioning profiles
      script: |
        PROFILES_HOME="/Users/vadivel/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
        mkdir -p "$PROFILES_HOME"
        PROFILE_PATH="$(mktemp "$PROFILES_HOME"/$(uuidgen).mobileprovision)"
        echo ${CM_PROVISIONING_PROFILE} | base64 --decode > $PROFILE_PATH
        echo "Saved provisioning profile $PROFILE_PATH"
    - name: Add signing certificate to keychain
      script: |
        echo $CM_CERTIFICATE | base64 --decode > /tmp/certificate.p12
        keychain add-certificates --certificate /tmp/certificate.p12 --certificate-password $CM_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD
    - name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
      script: |
        xcode-project use-profiles
    - name: Build .ipa
      script: |
        xcode-project build-ipa --project "$XCODE_PROJECT" --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
  artifacts:
    - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
    - /Users/vadivel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.dSYM
  publishing:
    email:
        recipients:
          - xxxxx@gmail.com
        notify:
          success: true
          failure: true
```

Comment: Do you have any pods? Do you use xcworkspace?

Comment: No, I didn't have any pods and I didn't use xcworkspace

Comment: Add your `yaml` above, double check your project and scheme.

Comment: I have added the full yaml file code above

Comment: Is your scheme correct?

Comment: yes correct, "TestApp"

Comment: Ok, it is quite hard to debug, I think you should start from scratch add one by one and check building it without all the script and extras.  Follow this one by one, there are some YouTube tutorials just for building, watch them and start one by one, also if you are manually signing it try automatically signing it. https://docs.codemagic.io/getting-started/building-a-native-ios-app/

Comment: @Velu are you able to solve this issue.  I'm stuck on the same.